# Saving NSMutableDictionary containing UIButtons in the NSUserDefults

Tags: ios

I am trying to save a NSMutableDictionary containing UIButtons in the NSUserDefults in this way:

```
[UserFolderDictionary setObject:FolderButton forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)numberFinal]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UserFolderDictionary forKey:@"UserFolderDictionarySaved"];
```

The app crashes with the error 'attempt to insert non-property list object'. To re-catch it I tried this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* UserFolderDictionary = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"UserFolderDictionarySaved"] mutableCopy];
```

FolderButton is a normal UIButton with a tag and a background image.

Comment: You can't save a button in the UserDefaults. You could save the properties you need, and re-create the button after reading its properties from the UserDefaults.

Comment: Why are you trying to save views to NSUserDefaults? Update your question with what you really need to do and someone can offer a better solution.

Comment: I need to store the images for each button

Comment: So save the images as needed. NSUserDefaults should contain some data, not views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save buttons in NSUserDefaults, and furthermore you SHOULDN'T save buttons in NSUserDefaults.

Buttons are view objects, not model objects. You should save state information from your buttons, and then use that information to recreate your button.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this.

`

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[myDictionary setObject:button forKey:@"myBtn"];

//save nsdata       
 NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myDictionary];
[userDefaults setObject:data forKey: @"SavedBtn"];
 [userDefaults synchronize];

//now retrieve it 
 NSData *data1 = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"SavedBtn"];
 NSDictionary *dict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data1];
```

`
Hope that Helps!